# Can I use the this keyword inside the zoomed callback in apexcharts?

Tags: apexcharts

Sorry this could be a trivial Javascript callback related question. When I zoom I want to call a function from the parent props. Is it possible to do this anyway? Or send additional props to the ReactApexChart component?

```
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
render() {
    let options = {
      ...,
        events: {
          zoomed: function(chartContext, { xaxis, yaxis }) {
            //I want to call this.props.setStartTime(xaxis.min)
          },
        ....
        }
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="area" height={350} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an arrow function to preserve `this`

```js
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let options = {
      ...,
        events: {
          zoomed: (chartContext, { xaxis, yaxis }) => {
            this.props.setStartTime(xaxis.min)
          }
        }
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="area" height={350} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```